# How to install Eclipse TypeScript plugin?

Tags: typescript, eclipse-plugin

I've searched the web and a couple of plugins appears in Eclipse Marketplace. But if I try to install any of them, none seems available. An example screenshot is shown below:

[image]

Any suggestions? Is anyone using these plugins?

Comment: Did you try installing it from the update site directly? http://eclipse-update.palantir.com/eclipse-typescript/  more info here: https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you've tried is not an update site, just the page of MarketPlace that contains the details of the plug-in. It looks like the plug-in you're trying to install (there are several TypeScript integrations, so plenty to choose from) is at this update site: http://oss.opensagres.fr/typescript.ide/1.3.0/ so try that. Just to be clear, the MarketPlace page at http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript-ide contains the description and a couple of ways of installing; either drag the Install button to a running eclipse instance or click the download icon to get the URL for the update site.